# Groupby column and aggregate consecutive rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have the dataframe below. I'd like to get a groupby for the class number only for consecutive values and create the following output. I would think there is an existing function that can collapse rows but not sure which one it is.

```
INPUT
```

| Class Number | Start | End | Length |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 58.063 | 58.169 | 0.106 |
| 1 | 58.169 | 58.25 | 0.081 |
| 1 | 58.25 | 58.45 | 0.2 |
| 1 | 58.45 | 58.567 | 0.117 |
| 1 | 58.567 | 58.585 | 0.018 |
| 2 | 58.585 | 58.748 | 0.163 |
| 2 | 58.748 | 58.85 | 0.102 |
| 2 | 58.85 | 58.979 | 0.129 |
| 2 | 58.979 | 59.078 | 0.099 |
| 2 | 59.078 | 59.175 | 0.097 |
| 2 | 59.175 | 59.287 | 0.112 |
| 2 | 59.287 | 59.408 | 0.121 |
| 2 | 59.408 | 59.558 | 0.15 |
| 2 | 59.558 | 59.742 | 0.184 |
| 2 | 59.742 | 59.853 | 0.111 |
| 2 | 59.853 | 59.891 | 0.038 |
| 2 | 59.891 | 60.159 | 0.268 |
| 2M | 60.159 | 60.176 | 0.017 |
| 2M | 60.176 | 60.337 | 0.161 |
| 2M | 60.337 | 60.41 | 0.073 |
| 2M | 60.41 | 60.499 | 0.089 |
| 2M | 60.499 | 60.656 | 0.157 |
| 2M | 60.656 | 60.776 | 0.12 |
| 2M | 60.776 | 60.874 | 0.098 |
| 2M | 60.874 | 61.004 | 0.13 |
| 2M | 61.004 | 61.226 | 0.222 |
| 2M | 61.226 | 61.246 | 0.02 |
| 2M | 61.246 | 61.499 | 0.253 |
| 2 | 61.499 | 61.547 | 0.048 |
| 2 | 61.547 | 62.156 | 0.609 |

```
OUTPUT
```

| Class Number | Start | End | Length |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 58.063 | 58.585 | 0.522 |
| 2 | 58.585 | 60.159 | 1.574 |
| 2M | 60.159 | 61.499 | 1.34 |
| 2 | 61.499 | 62.156 | 0.657 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with [`groupby aggregate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html#pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-aggregate) with groups created via [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html#pandas-series-cumsum) based on where `'Class Number'`s change:

```
new_df = (
    df.groupby(df['Class Number'].ne(df['Class Number'].shift()).cumsum())
        .aggregate({'Class Number': 'first',
                    'Start': 'first',
                    'End': 'last',
                    'Length': 'sum'})
        .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

`new_df`:

```
  Class Number   Start     End  Length
0            1  58.063  58.585   0.522
1            2  58.585  60.159   1.574
2           2M  60.159  61.499   1.340
3            2  61.499  62.156   0.657
```

Or if `'Start'` and `'End'` values instead of `'first'` and `'last'` should be `'min'` and `'max'`:

```
new_df = (
    df.groupby(df['Class Number'].ne(df['Class Number'].shift()).cumsum())
        .aggregate({'Class Number': 'first',
                    'Start': 'min',
                    'End': 'max',
                    'Length': 'sum'})
        .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

Results same as above in this case.

Comment: Works great, thank you for that. I didn't know of the `shift()` function.